# Xor c code - need an explanation

Tags: c++, xor

could someone explain me what `XOR`,`(^)` does in the fallowing code exaclly and how come the function is a pointer?

```
char *strReverse(char *str)
{
      char *pb, *pe;

      for (pb = str, pe = str + strlen(str) - 1; pe > pb; ++pb, --pe)
      {
            *pb ^= *pe;
            *pe ^= *pb;
            *pb ^= *pe;
      }
      return str;
}
```

Comment: http://betterexplained.com/articles/swap-two-variables-using-xor/. Note that using `std::swap` will perform better.

Comment: The xor trick is a stupid trick (that does not gain you anything apart from unreadable code) for swapping two values without using an extra variable.

Comment: well i saw that trick and i was curios but tank you for telling me you opinion altought it is a nice trick...  but it works for +ints only

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function is not a pointer, but returns a `char*`.

The function reverses a string.

This `XOR` technique is used to swap two elements without any extra memory. As you can see, the loop iterates through the string's start and end, and swaps the two `char`s.

Comment: @LokiAstari I knew there was a more appropriate term!

Answer (score 1):

using xor like this is a different way for swapping two values in a memory without using a temporary variable. I recommend [bit hacks](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html) for other bit hacks